# Translating Image in Xaml with Windows 8

Tags: animation, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm new to XAML and Windows 8. I would like to Animate an Image from off the screen to some X, Y value. I have successfully moved the image from its original position to a point using

```
var translate = new TranslateTransform();
translate.X = 400;
translate.Y = 400;
MyImage.RenderTransform = translate;
```

where MyImage is defined in the XAML.

However, I would like to use an linear easing animation so it slides from one point to another. I have seen the use of Storyboards in some examples but I'm not sure how to complete my task. Also, I want to set the point the image ends up at in code and not in XAML.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames x:Name="TranslateX" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="imageToAnimate">
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames x:Name="TranslateY" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="imageToAnimate">
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Image x:Name="imageToAnimate" Source="/Assets/Logo.png" Width="150" Height="150" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Image.RenderTransform></Image>
</Grid>
```

In code you can set the points to translate

```
        EasingDoubleKeyFrame animateX1 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
        animateX1.KeyTime = new TimeSpan(0);
        animateX1.Value = 1;
        EasingDoubleKeyFrame animateX2 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
        animateX2.KeyTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
        animateX2.Value = 250;

        EasingDoubleKeyFrame animateY1 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
        animateY1.KeyTime = new TimeSpan(0);
        animateY1.Value = 1;
        EasingDoubleKeyFrame animateY2 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
        animateY2.KeyTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
        animateY2.Value = 250;

        TranslateX.KeyFrames.Add(animateX1);
        TranslateX.KeyFrames.Add(animateX2);

        TranslateY.KeyFrames.Add(animateY1);
        TranslateY.KeyFrames.Add(animateY2);

        Storyboard1.Begin();
```

Comment: This works, thank you. However, I'm looking to animate multiple images in code and would like to re-use the Storyboard since I don't know how many times I will need to animate the images. Is it possible to create the storyboard and images all in C# and not in XAML?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392720/how-to-set-same-animation-to-dynamically-created-images-in-winrt